# Why aren't directories removed from others' local repositories?

Tags: git

I have a project which I removed an entire directory on my local, committed the changes, and published to a new branch on the remote.

People who have already cloned the project checked out the branch and it appears to still contain that directory and all of its sub directories, but they are all empty.

People who have not already cloned the project do so, check out the branch locally, and everything is as I intended.

What causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not version control directories, only files.

Directories are created by Git when a file needs to be put in it. When the file is removed, the directory will remain if anything is in it.

Comment: Git will remove the directory if it's completely empty, but not if it contains files (including untracked or ignored files).

Comment: So it will not remove the directory if it has a sub-directory?

Comment: @JuJoDi Correct, if a subdirectory has been created the directory will not be removed by git, even if it is otherwise empty.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Is there a reason why the deletion of empty directories is not recursive such that the lowest level one is deleted first, and so as long as all of the subdirectories are empty the top level directory would still be removed?